# How can I get todays timestamp at 4pm?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time, timestamp

I am looking for a way to receive the timestamp of today's 4pm in JavaScript.

When I use this code

```
Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
```

it give me the current timestamp. How can I specify just the hour to be static, the rest to rely on the current day?

Comment: I think your easiest solution is using the `setHours`, `setMinutes`, etc. functions. `(new Date()).setHours(16).setMinutes(0).setSeconds(0).setMilliseconds(0);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by getting the current DateTime and change the hour, code:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(16,0,0,0);//The setHours method can take optional minutes, seconds and ms arguments, but you can also do setHours(16)
Math.floor(d / 1000);
```

Comment: Winner: Shortest code and wanted result (timestamp)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setHours(16);
date.setMinutes(0);
date.setSeconds(0);
Math.floor(date.getTime() / 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code to do that:

`var d = new Date();//stores current date time`

`d.setHours(16);//4pm = 16 in 24 hour time`

Now when you'll type console.log(d), you'll get the following required result.
`Tue May 12 2015 20:58:24 GMT+0500 (PKT)`

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate a `Date` object and set the hours like so:

```
var d = new Date;
d.setHours(16);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours